# Search word document for month/date and replace with different month/date

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my new job I'm sending invoices with personalized, dated letters. Each month I go into a word doc for each client and update the date from whatever date we last send an invoice to the date we're sending the current invoice. I know basically nothing about coding, but I have managed to get something together that will search for a month and replace it with a new month. I did this by googling and piecing it together. I have no idea if its good or not, but it works.

```
Sub Test()

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "April"
    .Replacement.Text = "May"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

My question is, is there a way to search for a date like "Month DD, YYYY" and replace it with a date of my choosing? Also, it won't necessarily be the same previous date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49802427/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need VBA if you don't want to use it --- a [wildcard search](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7) will do.

1. Open the Replace dialog, hit More (if necessary), then check Use wildcards.
2. In the "Find what" box, put `MMMM[ ^s][0-9]{1,2},[ ^s][0-9]{4,4}`, but with the actual month you want in place of `MMMM`.  It's case-sensitive.
3. In the "Replace with" box, put the new date.
4. Hit Replace All.

Bingo!  E.g., if `MMMM`=`March`, any date in March will be replaced with the new date you specify.

#### Explanation

- `[ ^s]` is a space or nonbreaking space
- `[0-9]{1,2}` is either one or two (`{1,2}`) digits (`[0-9]`).
- Similarly, `[0-9]{4,4}` is exactly four digits.

#### VBA

For completeness, here it is:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub Test()

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "March[ ^s][0-9]{1,2},[ ^s][0-9]{4,4}"      ' ###
        .Replacement.Text = "April 1, 2018"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        '.MatchCase = False         ' ### Not relevant when using wildcards
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True                              ' ###
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

PS- Congratulations on starting out in VBA!  Your code looks fine to me - it's pretty close to what you'd get from the macro recorder for the same operation, but cleaner.  Two tips you don't need just yet :) — always use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and `Dim` your variables with specific types.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It does pretty much exactly what I wanted it to do, in VBA or just straight from the Replace dialog box. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jbrandenburg You're welcome!  As the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) will tell you, the preferred way to say "thanks" on SO is to upvote helpful answers, and accept (checkmark) the one that best solves your problem.  Those actions provide signposts to guide future readers with the same problem to a useful answer.  Much appreciated!